# Archive links for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, archives

How do you display a list of archive(last 6 months or so) for custom post types?
Something like this: https://blog.evolveformazione.com/

Comment: What have you tried so far? Maybe check out https://wphierarchy.com/ and read over the [Template Hierarchy docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: On index.php file which displays all blog posts, I'm using `<?php the_widget( 'WP_Widget_Archives' ); ?>`- which spits out a list of all archive from feb 2019. But the same would not work for custom post types! How do I get around this, please?

Comment: The answer is here: https://wphierarchy.com/, you just need to read the article. The WordPress Codex also has the answer here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/ which you can copy and paste.

Comment: Many thanks @JohanPretorius. After reading through and some extra googling, the below comment worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still struggling with this, here's a solution:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'     =>  'your_custom_post_type',
'post_status'     =>  'publish'
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```

Then output it anywhere in your template like so: `//Output
   <?php wp_get_archives($args); ?>`